# SunCertPathBuilderException when running a Java application in Docker Toolbox

Tags: java, docker, https, windows-7, docker-toolbox

I have a Spring Boot Java application, which I want to run inside a Docker container. The application communicates with another service on internal network over HTTPS, but when I run the Docker container, I get the following exception (cause by the HTTPS connection):

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I had the same exception on my dev machine as well, which I fixed using [this tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/).

**What I tried**

- Many advices pointed out that `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` variable needs to be correctly set, but when I run `docker-machine env default`, I see it pointed to `C:\Users\username\.docker\machines\machine\default`.
- I tried to get the certificate and put it to this folder using [this advice](https://superuser.com/a/641396)
- I tried adding `-Dtrust_all_cert=true` Java option to disable certificate check
- I tried to switch from `org.spotify.dockerfile-maven-plugin` to `org.spotify.docker-maven-plugin` with [this settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815411/docker-maven-plugin-clientprotocolexception-windows-10-using-docker-toolbox/41621300#41621300)
- I followed [this tutorial](https://adamtuttle.codes/TIL-adding-a-jvm-ssl-cert-docker/) and managed to add the certficiate to `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` and also to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts` in the Docker image.

None of these solutions worked, unfortunatelly.

**My question**

What should I do to get rid of this exception?

**My Dockerfile (after applying previous solutions)**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
# to enable file writes
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/trip-force-0.1.0.jar app.jar

# java cacerts
COPY ./res/timur.domain.local.cer /timur.domain.local.cer
ENV CACERTS  /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
RUN keytool -noprompt -import -alias timur -keystore ${CACERTS} -file /timur.domain.local.cer

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dtrust_all_cert=true"
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom  -jar /app.jar" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What finally did the trick was the solution, that I probable should have tried in the beginning, as it was what fixed the problem on my dev machine.

Using [this tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/) (and downloading the InstallCert.java file from [here](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert)) I just copied the generated `jssecacerts` file inside the Docker image using this command in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./res/jssecacerts /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks I spent a lot of time with this, I use a Alpine docker with Apache 8 and jvm 1.8 oracle, I have problems wiht Meta APIS (https://api.twilio.com) and must to import the CA DigiCert. Thanks a lot.